# How to perform a random-effects model to include more than one category?

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

**Sample Panel Data**

| Year | Firm_ID | Region | Industry | ROE | ROA | Tobin_Q | ESG | Leverage | Age | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 1 | Asia/Pacific Rim | Oil_and_Gas_Refining_and_Marketing | 12.19 | 6.22 | 1.17 | 51.24 | 1.45 | 1.58 | 6.51 |
| 2013 | 1 | Asia/Pacific Rim | Oil_and_Gas_Refining_and_Marketing | 11.88 | 6.06 | 1.12 | 55.37 | 1.47 | 1.59 | 6.56 |
| 2014 | 1 | Asia/Pacific Rim | Oil_and_Gas_Refining_and_Marketing | 11.82 | 5.69 | 1.17 | 57.85 | 1.51 | 1.6 | 6.63 |
| 2015 | 1 | Asia/Pacific Rim | Oil_and_Gas_Refining_and_Marketing | 11.3 | 5.05 | 1.05 | 48.76 | 1.5 | 1.61 | 6.7 |
| 2016 | 1 | Asia/Pacific Rim | Oil_and_Gas_Refining_and_Marketing | 13.22 | 5.39 | 1.13 | 52.48 | 1.48 | 1.62 | 6.78 |
| 2017 | 1 | Asia/Pacific Rim | Oil_and_Gas_Refining_and_Marketing | 12.07 | 4.56 | 1.18 | 41.74 | 1.44 | 1.63 | 6.85 |
| 2018 | 1 | Asia/Pacific Rim | Oil_and_Gas_Refining_and_Marketing | 12.95 | 4.72 | 1.28 | 53.31 | 1.43 | 1.64 | 6.91 |
| 2019 | 1 | Asia/Pacific Rim | Oil_and_Gas_Refining_and_Marketing | 11.63 | 4.35 | 1.42 | 42.56 | 1.46 | 1.65 | 7 |
| 2020 | 1 | Asia/Pacific Rim | Oil_and_Gas_Refining_and_Marketing | 9.37 | 3.63 | 1.22 | 41.74 | 1.47 | 1.66 | 7.07 |
| 2012 | 2 | EMEA | Electric_Utilities | 14.4 | 5.95 | 1.1 | 77.27 | 1.55 | 1.11 | 4.39 |
| 2013 | 2 | EMEA | Electric_Utilities | 12 | 5.03 | 1.2 | 72.31 | 1.59 | 1.15 | 4.37 |
| 2014 | 2 | EMEA | Electric_Utilities | 30.2 | 14.1 | 1.24 | 66.53 | 1.51 | 1.18 | 4.33 |
| 2015 | 2 | EMEA | Electric_Utilities | 33.56 | 18.75 | 0.94 | 66.53 | 1.42 | 1.2 | 4.36 |
| 2016 | 2 | EMEA | Electric_Utilities | 3.65 | 2.22 | 0.98 | 67.77 | 1.37 | 1.23 | 4.34 |
| 2017 | 2 | EMEA | Electric_Utilities | 6.53 | 3.96 | 1.07 | 64.46 | 1.35 | 1.26 | 4.34 |
| 2018 | 2 | EMEA | Electric_Utilities | 6.77 | 3.82 | 1.23 | 65.7 | 1.43 | 1.28 | 4.35 |
| 2019 | 2 | EMEA | Electric_Utilities | 11.94 | 6.48 | 1.28 | 66.12 | 1.46 | 1.3 | 4.37 |
| 2020 | 2 | EMEA | Electric_Utilities | 14.06 | 4.49 | 1.08 | 57.02 | 1.27 | 1.32 | 4.76 |
| 2012 | 3 | Americas | Oil_and_Gas_Storage_and_Transportation | 19.13 | 6.91 | 1.89 | 11.57 | 1.65 | 1.11 | 4.56 |
| 2013 | 3 | Americas | Oil_and_Gas_Storage_and_Transportation | 18.29 | 6.83 | 2.17 | 12.81 | 1.64 | 1.15 | 4.6 |
| 2014 | 3 | Americas | Oil_and_Gas_Storage_and_Transportation | 16.75 | 6.38 | 2.1 | 12.81 | 1.66 | 1.18 | 4.67 |
| 2015 | 3 | Americas | Oil_and_Gas_Storage_and_Transportation | 13.15 | 5.25 | 1.64 | 14.46 | 1.66 | 1.2 | 4.69 |
| 2016 | 3 | Americas | Oil_and_Gas_Storage_and_Transportation | 11.87 | 4.98 | 1.67 | 19.01 | 1.66 | 1.23 | 4.72 |
| 2017 | 3 | Americas | Oil_and_Gas_Storage_and_Transportation | 12.55 | 5.25 | 1.64 | 19.01 | 1.65 | 1.26 | 4.74 |
| 2018 | 3 | Americas | Oil_and_Gas_Storage_and_Transportation | 17.98 | 7.49 | 1.52 | 28.51 | 1.66 | 1.28 | 4.76 |
| 2019 | 3 | Americas | Oil_and_Gas_Storage_and_Transportation | 18.89 | 7.74 | 1.6 | 34.3 | 1.66 | 1.3 | 4.79 |
| 2020 | 3 | Americas | Oil_and_Gas_Storage_and_Transportation | 15.37 | 6 | 1.29 | 33.88 | 1.68 | 1.32 | 4.81 |

For example, my fixed effects model is using the code:

```r
dummyvar = lm(ROE ~ ESG + Leverage + Age + 
    Size + factor(Industry) + factor(Region), 
    data=Updated_Age_Data)
```

Whereby the industry and regions are the dummy variables. ROE is the dependent, ESG is my independent, and leverage, age, and size are my control variables.

How do I apply the same concept to a random effects model?
Would either of these be the correct code? As I want the output to show the significance of ROE based on region and industry type.

```r
random1  <- plm(ROE ~ ESG + Leverage + Age + 
    Size + Region + Industry, 
    index=c("Firm_ID", "Year"), model="random", 
    data=Updated_Age_Data)
```

**OR**

```r
random2  <- plm(ROE ~ ESG + Leverage + Age + 
    Size + Industry + Region, 
    data=Updated_Age_Data, model="random")
```

List of acronyms/explanations:

- ROE = Return on Equity
- ESG - Proxy for corporate social responsbility
- ROE is my dependent variable
- ESG is my independent variable
- Age, Size and leverage are my control variables

Comment: Welcome to stack! Please @Emma, try to give a toy dataset to provide a minimal reproducible example (see [mcve]) so that people here can gives you answer that can be tested and reproduced by otehrs

Comment: @denis Hi, apologies for that. I just tried to include a sample in, my unsure how to format it nicely in the snippet code as per the link you sent.

Comment: try to use `dput` on your dataset

Answer (score 0):

As you do not give a dataset, I will try to give you some guidance without having the possibility to test.

I think you need to have a look at the `lme4` and `lmerTest` packages for the mixed effect linear regressions.

From what I understand, `Industry` and `Region` are your cluster variables. Your regression with random intercept would look like

```r
lmer(ROE~ESG+Leverage+Age+Size+(1|Industry)+(1|Region),
     data = Updated_Age_Data)
```

For random slopes of your independent variable:

```r
lmer(ROE~ESG+Leverage+Age+Size+(1 + ESG|Industry) + (1 + ESG|Region),
     data = Updated_Age_Data)
```

You could also want to use GEE from the `gee` package or `geepack` package, but these do not allow for 3 levels random models. If you want just 2 level random variable, `gee` would do the trick too (without estimating the variance of intercepts and slopes)

Comment: Hi, apologies if I'm wrong. But I did some tests which told me to use the random-effect model. Would the mixed effect linear regression model not be something entirely different? Thank you for the reply nevertheless!

Comment: mixed-effect and random effect are two ways of naming the same thing actually, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model

Comment: Sorry, I should have worded it better. I'm looking to just get the results using just the random-effects model, rather than mixing the two! The fixed-effects code was there just for example haha.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.